# Can i call a method call before executing my Rest API which is coming from Angular

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop, spring-rest

Can i call a method before executing my Rest API which are coming from Angular  I am making a post rest call (predefined API from activiti) from angular and i need to call a method before executing the rest API based on the method response i have to decide either i have to call the API or not .Can i use spring AOP? please provide your suggestions and give me any reference links so that i can go head with the implementation

```
[POST] http://localhost:8080/myapp/test
before this rest call i have to call a method based on the response i have to decide whether i have to call api or not[some how i traps my request and then navigate to the api]
```

Comment: Yes of course, you can use spring AOP. In fact that is the best solution available in these scenarios. Just add a '@Before' advice with Pointcut exüression for @RequestMapping

Comment: yes kiran, but the problem is my @RequestMapping is part of jar file . we are using some activiti API's to complete the tasks . since its a part of jar file i can't modify the class file. is thjere any way we can configuare it in spring xml file

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comments, @Narendra, you dont have to modify your controller, what I meant is create a aspect like this

```
    @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
        public void requestMapping() {}

    @Pointcut("within(de.some.package.controller.*) || within(de.some.package.aspect.*)")
    public void myController() {}

   @Around("requestMapping() && myController()")
   public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
           //This will be called before and after any method in the package controller or any method with @RequestMapping annotaion is called
            Object result=  joinPoint.proceed();
    }
```

This is around advice, which give you more control over the method call. You can also use `@Before`.
This is done from Java Annotations. I am sure you can do the same from xml as well. Here are a few examples.
http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-aop/aspectj-before-advice-example/
https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-aop-examples-advice/